# Playing background music with Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am new to Sprite Kit and currently developing my first Game.
Now I want to add some background music (and maybe later some effects) to it and tried it with this piece of code:

```
func playBackgroundMusic() {
        // 1 - Create player
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mySong", withExtension: "mp3")!
        let player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        
        // 2 - Play sound
        player.play()
    }
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. I noticed that when I play music and then run the game, the music stops but I can't hear my game music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `player` variable is local to the `playBackgroundPlayer` function. When you start playing the music, the function exits. When the function exits, `player` no longer exists. That would explain why the music stops.

The fix is to add a property for the AVAudioPlayer to the class or struct that contains the `playBackgroundPlayer` function. Create the AVAudioPlayer instance when you init the class or struct. Call the `play` function inside `playBackgroundPlayer`.

Comment: I’ve now added a class in which I added the AVPlayer but now it is saying  `Cannot use instance member
url within property initializer;
property initializers run before 'self' is available `

Comment: Edit your question and show the code you added. That will make it easier for people to figure out what's wrong and provide a solution.

Comment: I’ve added this code to my other variables on the top    `let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Jonathan Maiocco - Superhero (128 kbps)", withExtension: "mp3")!
        
        let player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url) ` Then I tried to start the player in the `sceneDidLoad ` func with `player.play()`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked now with the first solution. I first understood it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using an SKAction to play music:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417664-playsoundfilenamed

It works but it’s a little buggy at the moment. Larger MP3 files seem to crash the game or application.

I have been using one AVPlayer singleton for background music (December 2023) just because it’s more reliable.

However, AVPlayer cannot work concurrently with iTunes or Apple Music, so ideally SKAction is the preferred method in future builds of SpriteKit.